# why we are multiplying (temp>>11) with 2 to find the second in this code

Tags: c, binary, bit, operation

```
/*program to display hour,minute,and seconds*/

#include<stdio.h>

void times (unsigned int time);

unsigned short hours, minutes, seconds; /*global variables */

int main ()
{
  int time;

  puts ("enter any number(less than 24446)");
  scanf ("%u", &time);

  times (time);

  printf ("for time=%u\n", time);
  printf ("hours=%u\n", hours);
  printf ("minutes=%u\n", minutes);
  printf ("seconds=%u\n", seconds);

  return 0;
}

void times (unsigned int time)
{
  unsigned short int temp;

  hours = time >> 11;
  temp = time << 5;
  minutes = temp >> 10;
  temp = time << 11;
  seconds = (time >> 11) * 2;   /*why multiplying with two? */
}
```

Comment: I've added the backticks necessary to format your code as code, but please can you indent it properly.

Comment: Probably the program tries to handle a time stamp field of a directory entry in a FAT file system. See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#DIR_OFS_0Eh>. Your program seems to contain errors. You have `hours=time>>11;` and `seconds=(time>>11)*2;`. Just before the calculation of `seconds`, you have `temp = time << 11;` but you don't use the value `temp`. Your code seems to assume a certain bit size of the data type. Instead of assuming that bits get lost when you do a left shift you should use bitwise AND operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where this code comes from, but it seems to come from the direction of DOS file systems or something like that.

In some of these systems, date and time are bitwise coded in two 16 bit fields, and the seconds come in a granularity of 2 s.

Answer (score 1):

In old MSDOS days the file date and time were each stored in a 16-bit word. The time was only accurate to 2 seconds to make it fit.

```
15–11   Hours (0–23)
10–5    Minutes (0–59)
 4–0    Seconds/2 (0–29)

15–9    Year (0 = 1980, 127 = 2107)
 8–5    Month (1 = January, 12 = December)
 4–0    Day (1–31)
```

The left shifts in the code are there to clear the top bits to leave just the field wanted (could have done a bit mask instead).